# Action is being dispatched even though it is not in the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am playing around with react hooks and have come across a stumbling block with useReducer. I have created a simple pinPad which stores a pin to state, then will compare it to a constant and then route to a logged in page if the 2 match. (I know that it's not ver sophisticated!) I am using useReducer passing a reducer:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "addDigit":
            return state + action.payload;
        case "reset":
            return "";
        default:
            throw new Error();
    }
}
```

. At the moment I have not implemented the PIN checking but am instead using a  component to link to the "/LoggedIn" page.

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, "");
```

then:

```
<KeyDigit
    digit={v}
    key={v}
    className="keyDigit number"
    buttonAction={e =>
        state.length < 4 && dispatch({ type: "addDigit", payload: e })
                        }
/>
```

however, when I link to "/LoggedIn" I get a "TypeError: buttonAction is not a function" message, as if the dispatch is firing again after the  component has been rendered.

My router:

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/LoggedIn" component={LoggedIn} />
    </div>
</Router>
```

I don't know why anything which is contained within the App component should be dispatched when I am not rendering the App component, by the way, I can manually input the url of "/LoggedIn" and the error message does not occur so it seems to be something to do with Router.

KeyDigit Component:

```
const KeyDigit = ({ digit, className, children, buttonAction }) => {
let id = `id-${digit}`;
return (
    <div
        className={className}
        id={id}
        onClick={e => {
            buttonAction(digit);
        }}
    >
        <svg
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            viewBox="0 0 141 141"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="67" className="key keyNumber" />
        </svg>
        <span className="keyDigitNumber">{digit}</span>
        <div className="keyDigitNumber">{children}</div>
    </div>
);
```

};

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces this problem. At a minimum, please show the code for the `LoggedIn` component and the code that renders the link for navigating to `/LoggedIn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need prevent an event while component is loading

```
<KeyDigit
        digit={v}
        key={v}
        className="keyDigit number"
        buttonAction={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            state.length < 4 && dispatch({ type: "addDigit", payload: e })
                            }}
    />
```

as you are using `exact` `/` path even if you are on `http://localhost:3000`
it will load App component  so instead of `/` use `/home` 
then you will only be able to load it on  `http://localhost:3000/home`

Comment: Cant ge that to work, the error only comes up when routed to the next page.

Comment: can you add code for KeyDigit component for investigate

Comment: Sure, thanks for your time, I've edited the original post.

Comment: <div
className={className}
id={id}
onClick={e => {
  e.preventDefault();
buttonAction(digit);
}}
>

Comment: can you make above change that might help